# Chrome extension newline (\n) doesn't work in popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My popup.js receives an array, replaces `,` with `\n` and prints elements to the popup.html page. For some reason, The newlines aren't being formed and instead all I see is small spaces where the `,` used to be.

**popup.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>    
    <h3>Header issues</h3>
    <p class="hdrs">Fetching headers..</p>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
function fixArrayLines(response) {
  var sorted = response.toString().replace(/,/g,',\n');
  return sorted;
}
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: "getHDR"}, function(response) {
    var sortedRsp = fixArrayLines(response);
    document.querySelector("p.hdrs").textContent = sortedRsp;//if response null, replaces with empty
  });
```

**the array received (named "response"):**

```
var response =[aba,baba,gaga]
```

**unexpected result in the popup.html page**

```
aba baba gaga
```

I have a small CSS instruction for minimum popup size - thats all, and the manifest is set correctly. Why is this happening? How can I sort the array members properly line by line ? (in this way or any other)?

Comment: You need `.hdrs { white-space: pre }` in your CSS in order to handle newlines.

Comment: You are the best! thank you! :)